# Dragon Naturally Speaking 11: installing a non-standard language pack

Tags: dictionary, speech-to-text, language-pack, dragon-naturally-speaking

I've installed `Dragon Naturally Speaking 11`, and it's running perfectly in English. I've been asked to get it to recognize Afrikaans (a local South African language), but I'm having trouble - as far as I understand it shouldn't be too difficult to import a dictionary and train it, but I can't find an extensive dictionary for the language.

I also read somewhere that using an Office 2007 spellcheck pack might work, but it doesn't seem to.

*Does anybody have any suggestions as to the best process I should follow to install a non-standard language into Dragon Naturally Speaking?*

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for Afrikaans.

http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/dragon/@web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_017505.pdf :

> Dragon Naturally Speaking is available in a number of languages and
>   supports multiple accents as well:
>
> Languages
>
> - English
> - French
> - German
> - Spanish
> - Italian
> - Dutch
>
> Accents
>
> - Standard
> - Australian accented English
> - British accented English
> - Indian accented English
> - Inland Northern US (Great Lakes area)
> - Southern Asian accented English
> - Southern US
> - Spanish accented English
>
> Dragon Dictate for Mac is available in a number of languages and
>   supports multiple accents as well:
>
> Languages
>
> - English
> - French
> - German
> - Italian
>
> Accents
>
> - American
> - American – Inland Northern
> - American – Southern
> - American – Teens
> - Australian
> - British
> - Indian
> - Latino
> - Southeast Asian

Note that OS X Yosemite ships with 24 new dictation languages:

```
Arabic
- Saudi Arabia
Catalan
- Spain
Croatian
- Croatia
Czech
- Czech Republic
Danish
- Denmark
Dutch
- Netherlands
Finnish
- Finland
Greek
- Greece
Hebrew
- Israel
Hungarian
- Hungary
Indonesian
- Indonesia
Malay
- Malaysia
Norwegian Bokmal
- Norway
Polish
- Poland
Portuguese
- Brazil
- Portugal
Romanian
- Romania
Russian
- Russia
Slovak
- Slovakia
Swedish
- Sweden
Thai
- Thailand
Turkish
- Turkey
Ukrainian
- Ukraine
Vietnamese
- Vietnam
```